# Why can't I see edit history?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, revision-history

I just looked at this question ([Moving a Gargantuan Object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/209743/40101)) and either am going mad because a few people have seen it talk about morkoths and towers, but it no longer says that and I can't see an edit history.

What has happened here?

Comment: I also see no edit history, and [the post timeline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/209743/timeline) also makes no mention of edits. Maybe it got edited in the 5 minute grace period?

Comment: @doppelgreener That's probably what it is, because I can't see any edit history either.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I think you can tag this [status-bydesign]

Comment: @ThomasMarkov You're probably right, done.

Comment: Looks like the op actually had it in a now deleted comment and it was never part of the question after all. Thank you for the answer though, learn something every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the meta.se FAQ question, [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/674198)

---

> #### Grace period
>
> In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the
> revision history, a single user who makes a binding (not suggested)
> edit to a post is given a 5-minute [grace
> period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info),
> *except* if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The previous revision was a rollback.
> - The new revision is a rollback (includes cases where one selects to edit a prior revision and doesn't make any changes).
> - The user does not have the [remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)
>   privilege.
>
> During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into
> the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final
> outcome of all their edits within that 5-minute period. The grace
> period ends after exactly 5 minutes, or if:
>
> - Another user edits the post, at which time *their* grace period begins.
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor (ignores deleted comments).
> - If the post being edited is a question and an answer has been added since the previous revision (ignores deleted answers but *does*
>   include answers by the editor).
> - The post is a question, and it has been closed since the previous revision.